# In which controller should I define personal_detail page, where user can enter xtra details, like age, gender and weight. I am using devise (Ruby)?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I added extra parameters to my user :age, :weight, :height, :goal, :experience. But the controller for the user is through devise. So it is Application controller. I also have pages_controller where I have home and dashboard page. I wanted to create a page where user can enter personal information right after signing up. I have created a personal_details.html.erb in pages view. Now I am struggling to decide where should I define methods (aplication_controller or pages_controller). and should it be create or update method?

So far I have entered this to Aplication_controller

```
def new
    @user = User.new
  end
  def create
    @user = current_user
    @user = User.new(user_params)
  end
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :age, :weight, :height, :goal, :experience, :age)
  end
end
```

p.s I am a newbie in coding. Just finished 2 month bootcamp

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
  def create
    @user = current_user
    @user = User.new(user_params)
  end
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Thank you"
      redirect_to @user
      # Handle a successful update.
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :age, :weight, :height, :goal, :experience, :age)
  end
end
```

I don't know how to make it go to personal_details page right after signing up. Do I need to create a user_controller?

Answer (score 0):

All the methods you have added to ApplicationController do not belong there. ApplicationController is a site-wide ancestor for all the app's controllers, so the only things that should be there are methods, macros, filters that all controllers will use.

If Devise is handling your user signup, and has already defined UserController, then for the purpose you describe, you can just create a controller called (for example) UserDetailsController.

It is a misconception that there should be a pairing between controllers and models. As you are now seeing, controllers can be used to describe a workflow... in this case the user is entering their details.